# Grails JAXB element list null

Tags: grails, jaxb

I am using this Domain Class :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Target")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE )
class TargetElement {

    static constraints = {
        testPurpose()
    }

    @XmlAttribute(name="TestPurpose")
    String testPurpose

    // instead of bellow in comment use this 
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "Bag")
    @XmlElement(name="Child")
    List<Child> bag= new ArrayList<Child>()
    // 1..n Child
    static hasMany = [child:Child]
}
```

If I want to add Child elem, I use

```
def target = new TargetElement(testPurpose:"TestPurpose")
target.getBag().add(child)
target.save(flush:true)
if (target.hasErrors()){
    println '3 ***********' + target.errors
}
```

But I get `list == null` for bag.

Why my list is null? It is working for another project and only name is changing. May be my eyes are missing something...

Answer (score 0):

For whom who get the same trouble : having @XmlElementWrapper value(bag) to null 
in my Bootstrap.groovy.I have to declare :

```
ArrayList<Child> bag = new ArrayList<Child>()
bag.add(child1)
bag.add(child2)
targetElement.getBag().addAll(bag)
```

also I have met another issue whith GROM lazy loading and JAXB. Check that objects nested are retreived :
eg :

```
static mapping = {
    nested lazy: false
}
```

Hope this will helps